# toggle image using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, image

I am having an `img` inside `<p>` tag and if I `click` the `img` or the `<p>` it needs to be `toggled` and the img should `changed`.

I have done it by `adding`   `jQuery(this).attr("src", "img/hide.png");` but the img is not changing can any one suggest me the right path.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".content").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
            jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
        });
      });
</script>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.layer1 {
margin: -5px;
padding: 0px;
width: 860px;
}
```

This is my markup:

```
<div class="layer1">
<p class="heading"><img src="img/show.png" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 0 0;" /></p>
<div class="content"></div>
<p class="heading"><img src="img/show.png" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 0 0;" /></p>
<div class="content"></div>
<p class="heading"><img src="img/show.png" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 0 0;" /></p>
<div class="content"></div>
<p class="heading"><img src="img/show.png" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 0 0;" /></p>
<div class="content"></div>
<p class="heading"><img src="img/show.png" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 0 0;" /></p>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it ok if you change the image as background image of .heading?
so you can play .heading and .heading.hide and just toggleClass

Comment: @bondythegreat-Yes I have tried it before but it dosent look so good as the margins are problem for it and unable to set for that.

Comment: you can set the width&height of the container in .heading and just play a bit with background-position in css.. it's just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery(this).attr("src", "img/hide.png");`

In this context `this` will refer to the `.heading` (the `p` tag). You'll have to dig down a little deeper to reference the image:

`jQuery(this).find('img').attr("src", "img/hide.png");`

Here's a jsFiddle to show:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/yBFWM/

---

**Edit** I missed the content toggling bit of the question.

I've added a bit so that it will know what the 'active' content area is. Then when you click an image, it will hide the active content area and display the current. I also added a bit so the click handler wont toggle the content if it's already selected.

```
jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $contentArea = $this.next('.content');

    if (!$contentArea.hasClass('active')) {
        $(".content.active").slideToggle(500).removeClass('active');
        $contentArea.slideToggle(500).addClass("active");

        $this.find('img').attr("src", "http://www.google.com/images/icons/ui/doodle_plus/doodle_plus_google_logo_on_grey.gif");
    }
});
```

Comment: @JonathonBolster-Thank you so much for the quick reply and this is what I need but agin when I toggle it the img is not changing so how do I need to replace that.

Comment: @Kiran Sorry - I missed that bit! Please have a look at my edit (and the jsFiddle)

Comment: @JonathonBolster-No problem and I have looked at your fiddle it just slides sown and changes the img but if again I click the header the img should change.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the line `jQuery(this).attr("src", "img/show.png")` in the click-handler defined by `jQuery(".heading").click()`? In this case, your code cannot work because `this` refers to the `<p class="heading">`, not to the image.

Simply change the line to

```
jQuery('img',this).attr("src", "img/show.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','img/img1.png');
})

$("p").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','img/img2.png');
})

$("img").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','img/img1.png');
})

$("img").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','img/img2.png');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var imgShow = 'img/show.png';
        var imgHide = 'img/hide.png';
        jQuery(".content").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
            jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
            if (JQuery(this).find("img").attr('src') == imgShow ) {
                JQuery(this).find("img").attr('src', imgHide);
            } else {
                JQuery(this).find("img").attr('src',imgShow);
            }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: @bondythegreat-It's not changing the img.